# method of characteristics in a nutshell

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Good morning everybody, I need a quick reference for the following inhomogeneous first-order pde...

namely $$f(x,y,z)=A\partial_x\varphi+B\partial_y\varphi+C\partial_z\varphi,$$

where $\varphi\in C^1(\mathbb R^3)$ and $A,B,C$ are real constants (Say not zero). I think that this PDE can be treated with the method of characteristics (although all worked examples on the web deal with two variables $x,y$), in any case I have found that

$$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=A,\;\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}=B,\;\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dt}=C,$$

along with the so called compatibility condition $$\frac{\mathrm d\varphi}{\mathrm dt}=f(x,y,z).$$

If I am not wrong then the characteristic equation is

$$Bx=Ay+D_1,\; Cx=Az+D_2$$

for some real constants $D_1,D_2$.

How to write down the explicit solutions now? I am a bit confused...

Thank you for your help

-Guido-